# ¿Como obtener las dimensiones de imagen base64?

Tags: php

Desde laravel 5.6, quiero saber que dimensiones tiene una imagen que se esta generando el dropzone, este crea la imagen en base64.

El código del formulario es

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="{{ route('x') }}" class="dropzone" id="gallery-dropzone">
<input id="id_base64_data" name="base64" type="hidden">
<div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Arrastra tus imágenes aquí</span></div>
<div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name class="badge badge-success"></span>
```

El enctype es

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

El input es

Y el controlador esta asi

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{

        $image_url = Core::uploadImageB64($request->base64);
        $images = Core::saveImagesGallery($image_url);
        $imgurl = asset('uploads/images/'.$image_url);


        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'title' => '¡Exitoso!',
            'message' => "Ha agregado un slide de forma correcta",
            'data' => [
                'imgurl' => $imgurl,
                'image' => $image_url

            ]
        ]);

}
```

Bueno... en este caso el que tiene la imagen con código larguísimo es `$request->base64` solo pongo el principio del valor

```
 $request->base64 = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD
```

Comment: Jorge, creo que por error no se publicó parte de tu código. Puedes revisar tu pregunta y agregar lo que hace falta por favor?

Comment: no se si entiendo bien! quieres obtener las dimenciones de la imagen cuando es colocada en el dropzone?? porque esto seria con `javascript!` si quieres obtenerlas con laravel bastaria con solo `$data = getimagesize($request->base64);
 $width = $data[0];
 $height = $data[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, creo puedes saber el las dimensiones usando la librería de imagemagick, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como te puede funcionar.

```
convert image -format "%w x %h" info:
```

Saludos

https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php